# How to handle an imported git repo?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, migration, bitbucket

I imported my bitbucket (mercurial) repo to github and it seems to work except that I got a new root. When I used to clone from bitbucket, the root was `xxx` and now my root is `yyy/xxx` so I must travest one node into the directory and open that directory with pycharm instead. Is there a convenient way for me to arange so that when I clone the gihub repo, I will get the root `xxx` and not the new `yyy/xxx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `yyy/xxx` when cloning, that means your GitHub repo must have a single `xxx` folder.

You can, in your local clone, move everything back to root:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git mv xxx/* .
git add -A .
git commit -m "MOve everything to root folder"
git push
```